# Using Macros with Word 2007

Tags: microsoft-word-2007, macros

Yesterday, I made a macro to automate switching to a split view in the print layout.  It worked fine, and I added a button for it to the quick access toolbar.  All was good.  Now, today, the button is still there, but when I click on it, I get this error message, "The macro cannot be found or has been disabled because of your Macro security settings."  I have not changed the security settings.  What happened?  How can I get my macro back?  I don't want to have to remake it every time I start Word; that kind of defeats the purpose.  Thanks.

***ADDITIONAL INFOMRATION***

From Developer Tab -> Code group -> Macros button, I cannot find the micro anywhere in the dialog box that appears.  I looked through all the options in the "Macros in" drop-down.  Did the macro not get saved?

***ADDITIONAL INFOMRATION***

I just tried to remake the macro.  In the Record Macro window I gave it the name PageLayoutSplitView and left the "Store macro in" at the default setting of "All Documents (Normal.dotm)."  Again, it worked fine until I restarted Word.  Then the same problem as before.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looking through Word 2007 it looks like any macros that you want to be globally available need to be stored in "All Documents (Normal.dotm)". When you created the original file where did you save it?

Using the Visual Basic Editor (ALT+F11) you can verify whether or not the macro is saved in your Normal file. Referencing the example image below you can see any macros, in any open documents, by opening any Modules attached to the them.

[image: VBE]

Answer (score 0):

Click the *Microsoft Office Button*, and then click *Word Options*. Click *Trust Center*, click *Trust Center Settings*, and then click *Macro Settings*. If not changed, the default setting is "Disable all macros with notification". Make sure that it's selected. This way, you can choose when to enable macros on a case by case basis. Restart Word, and check if it gives the notification whether you want to disable or enable macros. Then select "enable".

Comment: Yes, that option is already selected.  Please see the additional information I posted.  Thanks.